# Sign in form not logging in after I enter details

Tags: php

I am creating a login form for a website that should redirect the user to the index page after they log in. The problem I'm having is that when I enter the details for logging in, it runs the error part of the code and I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong. I have gone through my code and even physically compared both the passwords and username and they match. Please help me with where I went wrong.

**config.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$host = 'localhost';
$host_user = 'root';
$host_pass = '';
$db_name = 'the_dms_db';

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $host_user, $host_pass, $db_name);

if (!$conn) {
    echo 'Could not connect to the database';
}

$name = '';
$surname = '';
$username = '';
$email = '';
$errors = array();

if (isset($_POST['register_user'])) {
    // receive inputs
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['surname']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $c_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['c_password']);

    // form validation that it is filled correctly
    if (empty($name)) {
        array_push($errors, "Name is required");
    }
    if (empty($surname)) {
        array_push($errors, "Surname is required");
    }
    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($email)) {
        array_push($errors, "Email is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }
    if ($password != $c_password) {
        array_push($errors, "Passwords to not match");
    }

    // check database to see if user exists
    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email = '$email' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $user_check_query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($user) {
        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
            array_push($errors, 'Username already exists');
        }

        if ($user['email'] === $email) {
            array_push($errors, 'Email already exists');
        }
    }

    // register user if no errors
    $pass_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    if (count($errors) == 0) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, username, email, password) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$username', '$email', '$pass_hash')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'You are now logged in!';
        header('location: ./index.php');
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Username is required');
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Password is required');
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = 'You are now logged in!';
            header('location: ./index.php');
        } else {
            array_push($errors, 'Wrong username/password');
        }
    }
}
```

**signin.php**

```
<?php
require_once './header.php';
include_once './config.php';
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
<section class="sign-in-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-area ">
            <h1>Sign In</h1>
            <form action="./signin.php" class="signin-form" method="POST">
                <?php include './errors.php'; ?>
                <section class="input-sections">
                    <input type="text" class="inputs form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username or Email">
                    <input type="password" class="inputs form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-form btn signin-btn" name="login_user" id="login_user">Sign in</button>
                </section>
            </form>
            <a href="./signup.php">Not yet a member? Register here!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**signup.php**

```
<?php
include './config.php';
require_once './header.php';
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
<section class="sign-in-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-area ">
            <h1>Sign up</h1>
            <form action="signup.php" class="signup-form" method="post">
                <?php include './errors.php' ?>
                <section class="input-sections">
                    <input type="text" class="inputs form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $name ?>">
                    <input type="text" class="inputs form-control" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Surname" value="<?php echo $surname ?>">
                    <input type="text" class="inputs form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $username ?>">
                    <input type="text" class="inputs form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $email ?>">
                    <input type="password" class="inputs form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <input type="password" class="inputs form-control" name="c_password" id="c_password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-form btn register-btn" name="register_user" id="register">Register</button>
                </section>
            </form>
            <a href="./signin.php">Already have an account? Sing in here!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**errors.php**

```
<?php if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
    <div class="error">
        <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
            <p><?php echo $error ?></p>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of `errors.php` file?

Comment: please see the edited question

Comment: what does the output from `errors.php` actually reveal about the error?

Comment: it runs the wrong username/password error when i try log in

Comment: If you use `password_hash` to initially hash the user's password then you DO NOT use `password_hash` to try to validate that same password on login - you should nstead use `password_verify` ( BUT NOT AS PART OF THE SQL!! )

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't the returned result have 1 row rather than 0 rows, if it's a match?

Change this

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 0)
```

To this

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1)
```

Comment: even after putting this code, when i click the login button, it runs the `wrong username/password` but if i don't hash the password when saving it to the database, it logs in and redirects to the index.php

Answer (score -1):

If you ignore the vulnerabilities within the sql statements you should analyse the following to see where you were going astray with the approach above. Using `password_hash` will generate a new hash on each invocation - so the hashed password will never ( hopefully ) match a newly generated hash. You need to use `password_verify` instead.

```
define('BR','<br />');
$password=$_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' LIMIT 1";
$results = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );

$rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc( $results );

if( password_verify( $password, $rs['password'] ) ){
    /* OK - The user supplied a good username/password combo */
}else{
    /* Bad Foo!!! The supplied password did not verify against the stored hash */
}
```

If you consider

```
$pwd='banana';
echo password_hash($pwd,PASSWORD_DEFAULT) . BR;
echo password_hash($pwd,PASSWORD_DEFAULT) . BR;
echo password_hash($pwd,PASSWORD_DEFAULT) . BR;
```

you will likely see results similar to:

```
$2y$10$7a4Cvzn51eYa3EJKary8zemJn4/GiFA.2fqYQrwd6QrRORIk552Wm
$2y$10$E5.28SSkQo2lZv11zilkBO1L35umAFzr5Zr2yKScX4nDgFkN.kTbK
$2y$10$HEzHOFT/7V972XDEB9uzRuU/dxHxRnSXs64wu1qdahJs2CSp3wwD6
```

As you can see they are all different...